# Can we style a column of tds in css without adding any class?

Tags: css

Here I want to add background color to the column Sunday without adding css class to it. Can we achieve it without adding a css class and inline style? Here's a sample [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uQRA9/)

/*------------------HTML----------------*/

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Sun</td>
    <td>Mon</td>
    <td>Tue</td>
    <td>Wed</td>
    <td>Thurs</td>
    <td>Fri</td>
    <td>Sat</td>
</tr>
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
</tr>
      <tr>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

/*------------------CSS----------------*/

```
table{
border:1px solid #ccc;
border-collapse:collapse;
padding:5px;
}
table td{
background:#f6f6f6;
padding:3px;
border:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can:

`td:first-of-type` will select first `td` i.e. first cell of all rows.

```
table tr td:first-of-type{//your code}
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/uQRA9/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Yes using [`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/%3afirst-child) pseudo class.

```
table  tr:first-child > td:first-child{
    background-color :red;
}
```

The above one is for older browsers. You can also use [`first-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3afirst-of-type) as shown by Hiral.

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/uQRA9/3/)**

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/uQRA9/2/

Yes you can.

For example :

```
table td:first-child {
    background: red;
}

table td:nth-child(4) {
    background: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
    tr>td:nth-child(1){

       background-color:red;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can style sun column and all under it with this

```
table   td:first-child{
  background-color :red;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MBehtemam/yM7vR/)

Answer (score 0):

You can manage by css, `:nth-child(0)` property provides selector specified index (0,....., n)

```
table td:nth-child(0){
   background:#f6f6f6;
    padding:3px;
   border:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

AND

```
table tr:nth-child(0){
       background:#f6f6f6;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
table tr:first-child td:first-child {
   background:...;
   ...
}
```